# Error retrieving command-line parameter

Tags: c++

In order to run my program you have to enter:

```
(program name) -s (a number) -f (the file name)
```

The problem I am stuck on is that the file name is in `string` and the command parameters are in `char`.

Here is my code so that I can illustrate my problem more clearly:

```
if(argc==1){
   cout << "Please Enter it in the Form of (prog -s (number of state) -f (file name)\n";
}   
if(argc==2){
   cout << "Please Enter it in the Form of (prog -s (number of state) -f (file name)\n";
}   
if(argc==3){
   cout << "Please Enter it in the Form of (prog -s (number of state) -f (file name)\n";
}   
if(argc==4){
   cout << "Please Enter it in the Form of (prog -s (number of state) -f (file name)\n";
}   
if(argc==5){

      if((argv[1][0]=='-'&& argv[1][1]=='s')&&(argv[3][0]=='-'&& argv[3][1]=='f')){
        int x;
         x=argv[2][0]-48;
         state *array;
         array= create_states(x);

         ifstream File;
         File.open(argv[4][0]);
```

On this line:

```
file.open(argc[4][0]);
```

I get an error.

Comment: `if (code.Formatting() == FormattingTypes::VeryBad) std::cout << "Please format your code!" << std::endl;`

Comment: sorry about that, i was editing it and when i finished editing it said that somebody had already edit it, whom i am thankful for.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
  ifstream File;
  File.open(argv[4]);
```

Additionally, if the file path contains spaces use double quotes.

Comment: @pnewbie happens to all of us :)